# Power series graphs?

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, homework

I would like to graph this function and its first 6 Taylor polynomials on the same axis, but I'm not sure how to start:

```
f[x_] = Exp[x];
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Please show what you've already done so we can help you to understand the problems you're facing. (Otherwise your question is just another _"Please do my hw for me"_)

Comment: Yeah I tried to copy and paste what i tried into the query but it would not let me submit it as it had a bunch of polynomials in it. I do see where you're coming from though, I really am trying to do it, I just could not figure that one out. @belisarius

Answer (score 5):

```
funcs = Tooltip /@ ({E^x,
      (Series[E^x, {x, 0, #}] // Normal) & /@
       Range[6]} // Flatten);

Plot[funcs, {x, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: Please read [this](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/459/193)

Comment: +1 just for (a) fancying up the plot with tooltips, and (b) using `Map` with `Range` rather than a more verbose use of `Table`.